# Android : Static Spinner values match based on DatePicker

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-datepicker

I have a `DatePicker` with a button that gives a DialogBox to select date and an EditText `txtDate` to set the date on it :

`Layout`:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.50"
                android:text="Pickup Date*"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

             <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/txtDatee"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="2.28" >

        </EditText>

              <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCalendar"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/date" >
        </Button>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="126dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pickup Time"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/hh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/mm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

onClick[`DatePicker`]:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == btnCalendar) {

        // Process to get Current Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Launch Date Picker Dialog
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        // Display Selected date in textbox

                         if (year < mYear)
                                view.updateDate(mYear,mMonth,mDay);

                            if (monthOfYear < mMonth && year == mYear)
                                view.updateDate(mYear,mMonth,mDay);

                            if (dayOfMonth < mDay && year == mYear && monthOfYear == mMonth)
                                view.updateDate(mYear,mMonth,mDay);

                        txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        Date newDate2 = c.getTime();
        dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newDate2.getTime());
        dpd.show();
    }   }
```

And also two spinners with id's `hh` and `mm` for the hours and minutes which have static array values.

```
String[] pickup_hour = { "HH", "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06",
        "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17",
        "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23" };

String[] pickup_min = { "MM", "00", "05", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30",
        "35", "40", "45", "50", "55" };



sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hh);

    sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            edsp3.setText(pickup_hour[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
    ArrayAdapter b3 = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, pickup_hour);

    b3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp3.setAdapter(b3);

sp4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mm);
    sp4.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            edsp4.setText(pickup_min[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
    ArrayAdapter b4 = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, pickup_min);

    b4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp4.setAdapter(b4);
```

The `DatePicker` is disabled for previous dates based on the current date.
So how do fix the hours and minutes based on the `DatePicker` Date?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:

This is what i've done inside the hour spinner :

```
sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hh);

    sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(); 


        int hour = c1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
Log.d("aaa", ""+hour);
            edsp3.setText(pickup_hour[position]);


                         if(position<hour)
                         {
                             Toast.makeText(OnlineBooking.this, "Choose greater hour",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }}
```

Comment: just to understand better, on the selection of date from date picker you want to set the spinners correct ?

Comment: yes, like for example the current time here is 12:30PM and date  is 21.03.2014, so if i choose the date as today's from the `DatePicker`, all times post 12:30PM should be disabled on the `Spinner`s or maybe error `Toast` on selection.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, It is always recommendable that you use the inbuilt **DatePicker** and **TimePicker** widgets of android.

Still if you wish to use spinners then populate the spinners programmatically

```
 System.currentTimeMillis();
```

will give you current time of device
then check current hour and minute and accordingly populate the spinners

Other Method would be by validating the same at the submit button click event

means check the selected time with current system time

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the clock system, either 24 hours or 12 hours system, get

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR); // or HOUR_OF_DAY
```

When the spinenrs `onItemSelected` listener gets called then, compare the values with what you have in the seconds, hours, and minutes variables, and accordingly display the message.

Comment: Nice. But i have a question. How do i add the current hours,minutes and seconds in the `onItemSelected` listener along with these values? 

`public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
     int position, long id)`

Comment: and why do you want to add them ? you mentioned that the user would be selecting them himself/herself isnt it ?

Comment: For comparing inside the listener? Isn't that required?

Comment: OnItemSelected will get called the moment the user selects an item from the spinner, so you could  just get the values of the hours, min from the variables inside it. In order to get the selected item value, do pickup_hour[position] (for the hour, for example)

Comment: Okay cool. But i'm having a hard time fixing it inside the listener. It doesn't work properly as desired. See `EDIT` above. Where did i go wrong